# How do I insert rows in multiple excel tables simultaneously without vba?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have 12 tables, 1 for each month. I want to be able to insert a row to all tables simultaneously without vba. Is this possible?

The tables are in different sheets if that matter.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Do you want to insert the row at the same point in each of the tables; i.e. insert between row 10 and 11? What have you attempted so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @CharlieRB good answer, IMO. I didn't know that about excel :-P -- it almost seems like OP wants something formula-based (like add a row of data under certain circumstances, or something like that), which I think would only be doable with macros

Comment: Unless the OP clarifies, we will never know. :-)

Comment: Hi again,

@CharlieRB something like what Code Jockey said is basically what I want. At the moment I can put my info on the first table and all the others update automatically, but if I add a row to the first table I need to manually add a row to each table.(The info still automatically fills in when I add rows in the other tables). What you answered charlieRB could work but its a bit tedious, especially since all my sheet tabs don't fit on one screen. I would also prefer it if it could be "Linked" to the tables instead of the position on the sheet.

Comment: Your comment is far longer and more detailed than your question. I would suggest you [edit] your question to include what you desire and, because we are not a coding service, also include what you have attempted to resolve this yourself. As far as my answer goes, it was based on what little information you gave. It answers your question of "*is this possible*". BTW, all the tabs do not need to be visible for this answer to work properly. Simply click one tab, hold the shift key and select the last tab. It will highlight all in between.

Answer (score 5):

You can make changes to multiple sheets simultaneously by selecting multiple tabs.

If you want to insert a row at the same point in all sheets, you can do the following.

- Select all of the tabs at the bottom of the workbook.
- Select the row below where you want the new row inserted.
- Right click and choose `insert` from the menu.

[image]

You now have a new row in all the selected sheets.

*NOTE: Remember to unselect the multiple sheets. Otherwise any further changes will occur on all selected sheets.*

Comment: Do I have to have that cursor set? :-P -- if so, where do I get it?

Comment: The answer provided does not work if the each of the sheets where you want to insert a row are "Format as Table". The "Insert" is greyed out.